# Computer laggs and gives BSOD kernel_data_inpage_error

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bsod, crash

My computer have been crashing more and more often the last half year. It have been giving me two different error messages.

```
KERNEL DATA ERROR
```

and

```
CRITICAL PROCESS DIED
```

This can happen at any time, no matter if I'm playing games or just surfing the internet. In the same time period my computer have been getting lots of lagg spikes, in most games that freeze the game for ½-2 second, and then return to good steady FPS. When it crash my mouse freezes for about 1-2 seconds before showing BSOD. First few times when this happened it asked me to use the windows installation disk to repair the system, all though it some how skipped that part before I got the chance to do that.

My computer specs are:

- Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB ( *With operation system* )
- 1863GB Western Digital WDC WD20EZRX-00D8PB0
- 2x DDR3-1600 DC - 8GB
- Intel Core i5 4590
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 970
- EVGA SuperNOVA 750W G2

What I've tried:

- Running a Chkdsk test on both my HDD and SSD (No errors)
- Checked ram with memory diagnostic tool (No errors)

I've also benchmarked my "HD Tune Hard Disk Utility" giving these results:

- Minimum:  25.5  MB/sec
- Mamximum: 418.3 MB/sec
- Average:  214.7 MB/sec
- Access Time: 0.1ms
- Burst Rate: 133.3 MB/sec
- CPU Usage: 31.9%

Also during an error scan it showed no errors at all.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem?

Comment: also replace the SATA cables. Damaged cables can also cause such crashes

Comment: Look at the Windows Event logs.  Are there any relevant errors or warnings?

Comment: At the time of one of the crashes I got this eventlog: `Critical; Kernel-Power; 41; (63)` then a minute after that it gave me a warning `Warning; Kernel-PnP; 219; (212)` with a FailureName: `\Driver\WudfRd` and DriverName: `ROOT\WPD\0000` No idea what this means

Answer (score 0):

Since you checked RAM and SSD already; it could still be a board issue which is uncommon.
Before you exchange your board you wont't come around reinstalling OS and clean/specific manufacturer drivers (not the microsoft auto installed drivers, especially for chipset and graphics). Could probably be software or driver related.